# With Ansible2, what is the correct way to use `lookup('file', item)` in `with_items` loop?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm using ansible 2.1.0. I'm looking at this page http://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/ and running the playbook of the following part:

```
- name: Add authorized keys for deploy user
  authorized_key: user={{ username }}
                  key="{{ lookup('file', item) }}"
  with_items: public_keys
```

When I run this, I get `[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using bare variables is deprecated. Update your playbooks so that the environment value uses the full variable syntax ('{{public_keys}}').` What is the not deprecated way to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/porting_guide_2.0.html#deprecated), bare variables in with_ loops should instead use the “{{var}}” syntax, which helps eliminate ambiguity.

So, It is just telling you to change this:

```
with_items: public_keys
```

to this:

```
with_items: "{{ public_keys }}"
```